# How do I make a default page for my website application with php?

Tags: php, indexing, directory, default

So I wish someone could give me a simple function or solution to put a default page on my site. That mean if the user try to access another page of my site he can't. He need to pass by this default page. Because in my site I have an admin page and I don't want a simple user to access it . I did some research on internet and I didn't find a good answer to my problem. Is there any way to do it simply by code and not changing the index file? To be more specific I want it to work only for one of my website and not for all . I have a login system for admin but since you can access the admin page directly by typing the address and not using  the login system it's a problem. I did try to do an index but the problem is when I try to log in then it redirect me on the default page and not on the admin page. I will appreciate any help. Best Regards a young programmer.

Here is the index.php

```
<?php

header('Location: Foredeckmain.php');
exit;
?>
```

Here is the login page

```
<?php
   ob_start();
   session_start();
?> 

<html lang = "en">

   <head>
      <title>Foredeck Login.com</title>
      <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">

      <style>
         body {
            padding-top: 40px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
            background-color: #6495ED;
         }

         .form-signin {
            max-width: 330px;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            color: #000000;
         }

         .form-signin .form-signin-heading,
         .form-signin .checkbox {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
         }

         .form-signin .checkbox {
            font-weight: normal;
         }

         .form-signin .form-control {
            position: relative;
            height: auto;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 16px;
         }

         .form-signin .form-control:focus {
            z-index: 2;
         }

         .form-signin input[type="text"] {
            margin-bottom: 0 px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
            border-color:#000000;
         }

         .form-signin input[type="password"] {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            border-top-left-radius: 0;
            border-top-right-radius: 0;
            border-color:#000000;
         }

         h3{
            text-align: ;
            color: #000000;
         }
         h1{
            text-align: ;
            color: #000000;
         }
      </style>

   </head>
```

```
   <?php
        $msg = '';

        if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['username']) 
            && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

            if ($_POST['username'] == 'foredeck' && 
              $_POST['password'] == 'foredeck1') {
              $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
              $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
              $_SESSION['username'] = 'foredeck';
              $msg ='Connexion Réussite';
              echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Connexion Réussite');
                window.location='foredeck.php'; </script>";

              header("refresh:3 location: foredeck.php");

            }else {
              $msg='Identifiant ou Mot de Passe incorrecte';
              $msg =  "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg')</script>";
               }
            }
     ?>
  </div> <!-- /container -->

  <div class = "container">

     <form class = "form-signin" role = "form" 
        action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
        ?>" method = "post">
        <h4 class = "form-signin-heading"><?php echo $msg; ?></h4>
        <h1>Foredeck@Admin</h1> 
        <h3>Entrer l'identifant et le mot de passe:</h3> 
        <input type = "text" class = "form-control" 
               name = "username" placeholder = "Identifiant " 
               required autofocus></br>
        <input type = "password" class = "form-control"
               name = "password" placeholder = "Mot de passe  " required>
        <br>

        <button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type = "submit" 
               name = "login">Se connecter</button>
     </form>
  </div> 
  </body>
```

Here is the logout part

```
<?php
   session_start();
   unset($_SESSION["username"]);
   unset($_SESSION["password"]);

   echo 'Déconnexion en cours...';
   header('Refresh: 2; URL = foredeckmain.php');
?>
```

Comment: Not sure what you trying to do. With only code (e.g. index.php), you cannot prevent other user to access the admin page with full url.  Moreover, you have a login system for admin, that should be not a problem if normal user access the admin page.  Maybe you can explain more what you trying to do

Comment: well if i type the exact adress of the webpage in the adress bar  that you get normaly  after log in as an admin , i can access the page and i don't want that. You have to login to acces this page otherwise it will redirect you on my homepage.  Login page => Admin page . If I type the adress of the Admin page i can access it that is the problem without login.

Comment: That you should change the "Login System" but not the **index** file.  You can access the admin page without login, it may your login system have store the session to _remember_ you.  You can re-access doesn't mean other ppl can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be true, I didn't understand a reason why you want to do it, but anyway.

But if I were you, I would make next steps

1. Configure Apache/Nginx/or what you're using for your website/ to process all your request through your default page(index.php or something like that)
2. In index.php you need to understand what page your user needs. If it doesn't exist show him 404 page.
3. If page exists and it's not your default page, and user didn't visit it before, redirect him there.
4. In your default page, write to session e.g `$_SESSION['passed_default'] = 1;`
5. Now, in your index.php you need to check

   `if(isset($_SESSION['passed_default']) && $_SESSION['passed_default'])
   {
   //Show desired page
   }
   else
   {
   //redirect to default
   }`

Comment: Well it's a survey let's say default page give you to option : 1- Admin then you have to login to edit the survey 2 - Customer answer the survey .